# Are there any factual comparison charts for triple stores compatible with Node.js?

Tags: node.js, charts, semantic-web, mean-stack, json-ld

I have a MEAN stack (AngularJS, Express, MongoDB, NodeJS) application that I want to convert into a semantic web application. I want to use JSON-LD to send around dynamic data and I (obviously) want it do be as fast as possible.

I have found [Jena-Fuseki](http://jena.apache.org/documentation/serving_data/index.html) (a triple store) which I can store and retrieve rdf data from, but there are no options for retrieving data in JSON-LD.

Does anyone know if there are any comparison charts for different Node.js compatible triple stores; especially when it comes to speed and serialization formats and cost?

Comment: Please note that "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."  This is written well, but it's off-topic for Stack Overflow.  To improve it, you really need to have a more specific technical question.  Once you've started working on some code, we can help you with the problems you encounter.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor if you have time, here is my new attempt at a better question :) [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24947939/how-do-i-build-a-semantic-web-app-with-a-mean-stack-and-json-ld)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to build an semantic web application using Node, you can try [stardog.js](http://clarkparsia.github.io/stardog.js/).  It's just a Node library, so it does not help with Angular or JSON-LD, but it can get you started.  Stardog does also provide access to the [web services](http://docs.annex.apiary.io/) used to build its web console.  These do use JSON-LD as the data format.

Comment: Do I need stardog to use stardog.js? I hope to build a web application I can charge for and Stardog seems to cost for commercial use. I don't have much money and they don't even write on their website how much it costs so it is probably not cheap. Or do you know?

Comment: Yes, stardog.js depends on Stardog, hence the name.  Stardog has a free version.  But wanting to charge for the software you write, but not pay for the software you use is an odd stance.

Comment: I didn't say I didn't want to pay, I said that I didn't have much money, and since they are not telling me how much they charge I assumed it was not cheap. Then I asked if you knew how much it was... since you seem to be working for them.